# Can someone help me with this mixed within-between ANOVA set-up: it's dizzying! :(

Tags: anova

**I want to do a mixed factorial (within-between) ANOVA but I am not sure what goes where. I find it incredibly dizzying. Which is the ‘within’ and which are the ‘between’ variables with this? And how many levels are in each?**

I am looking to see whether people gesture more after seeing a story with gesture than a story without gesture.

I had a narrator record 2 different stories (Story 1 and story 2) each with a gesture condition, and a no-gesture condition. Note I picked two stories that naturally elicit the same rate of gesture from participants.

In order to get the most data out of a few participants I had each participant see one story in either its gesture or no-gesture condition and the other story in either its gesture or no-gesture condition.

I broke the people, randomly, but evenly, into two groups of 17.

**Group 1 received:** Story 1 no-gesture/ story 2 gesture

Then I broke down the groups further into subgroups (randomly assigned but even) in order to have half get story 1 no-gesture first and half get story 2 gesture first. Thus, not everyone would get the same story order. For example:

Subgroup 1.0 got: Story 1 no-gesture/ story 2 with gesture
Subgroup 1.1 got: story 2 with gesture/ Story 1 no-gesture

**Group 2** received: Story 1 with gesture/ story 2 no-gesture

Subgroup 2.0 got Story 1 with gesture/ story 2 no-gesture

Subgroup 2.0 Got story 2 no-gesture/ story 1 with gesture

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you understand ANOVA and the within/between terminology when you just have several groups but none of the factors/levels?

Comment: @Dave, I'm not sure what you mean? Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: Basic F-test: measure dog heights, cat heights, and horse heights, then ask if there are differences in the means.

Comment: @Dave, so I think I understand it normally. Like if I was comparing two groups that would be between. In my experiment I can see that each person seeing Story 1 and story 2 is between, the story order, whether was gesture or no-gesture first are all between. but I'm confused what what would be the between with this. I don't really care about comparing the two groups so much. I more care about comparing the rate of gesture when they saw a story with gesture to when they saw one without.Anyway, very confused. :D

Comment: @Dave so I could use just a regular repeated measures anova?

Comment: I might be best for you to make sure you understand the basics of ANOVA how JBStatistics YouTube videos present the technique. Then you can move into more complicated concepts like repeated measures and experimental designs.

Comment: @Dave I know ANOVA a bit but I think though that this particular design feels very dizzying when I try and sort it out. I'll keep plugging away at it. thanks